# Strange result for grouping replace in a line

Tags: regular-expression, replace

The file contains only one line:
[image]

```
four_blank_space + "TE:" + one blank space + "trailers" + one blank space
```

I write a grouping replace:

```
:1s/\(\s\+\)\(.\+\):\s\+\(.\{-}\)\(\s\{0,}\)/\2/
```

I think that :

- The first group `\s\+` will match the four blank spaces at the beginning of the line.
- The second group `.\+` will match the string `TE`.
- `:\s\+` will match the string `:`  between `TE` and `trailers`.
- The third group `.\{-}` will match string  `trailers`.
- The last group `\s\{0,}` will match the last white space at the end of the line.

So replace the whole line with the second group, the output should be `TE`, but why the result is `TEtrailers` ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `:help 'incsearch'` enabled, what is matched by the regular expression you are typing is highlighted for you in real time.

This means that you get a chance to get your patterns right before they are actually used.

In this case, highlighting makes it obvious that your troubles start at capture group #2:

[image: sub]

where you are combining a crude atom (`.`) with a greedy quantifier (`\+`), and thus effectively matching everything after the four leading spaces.

After that, it only goes downhill because you are mainly using subsequent atoms and capture groups for their side-effects on the previous ones. On one hand you are saving yourself some thinking with `.\s` but, on the other hand, you are forcing yourself to do complicated things in order to fight the problems it creates. A bit like being lazy and a workaholic at the same time.

A smarter approach would be to use more refined patterns. The following substitution does what you want with mush less effort.

```
:1s/\s\+\([^:]\+\).*/\1
```

where the more precise `[^:]\+` doesn't extend beyond the `:` and thus allows us to finish lazily with `.*`.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem omits the latter half of the pattern, which affects what the original .+ will match (in particular, the colon forces .+ to stop, but the rest of the pattern matches empty and leaves a trailing string around during substitution).

Comment: It is omitted because it is irrelevant to the point I wanted to make. I will rewrite it to not confuse you and OP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *not* `.+`; it’s `(.{-})(\s{0,})`. Your pattern as written (my examples will all use `\v`) simply doesn’t match the whole line because the non-greedy match and the trailing space match are empty.

But `\v\s+(.+):\s+.{-}\s+` or `\v\s+(.+):\s+.+\s+` do, with the latter `.` repetitions working as intended because the space repetition was required to match at least once. This latter is effectively `\v\s+(.+):.*` if you aren’t using the other capture groups (which I’ve eliminated because I’m typing on mobile).

Answer (score 0):

With very magic and non-greedy match and group:

```
1s/\v\s+(.{-}):\s+(.{-})\s+/\2/
```

It is more clear and readable in logic though a bit of logger than other expressions.